# Ruby on Rails - Active Admin undefined method `except' for #

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, activeadmin

I'm getting a error in Active Admin when I put some code in my application_controller.rb. The error is (when i try access HomeConfig in active admin):

`undefined method 'except' for #<HomeConfig:0x007f8877cfda58>`

In this case, the error occurs when I put this code in application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # Code that cause the problem
  before_filter :contact_info, :home_config

  def contact_info
    @contact_infos = ContactInfo.all
  end

  def home_config
    @home_configs = HomeConfig.last
  end
end
```

And the log of error in terminal:

```
Started GET "/alumni/admin/home_configs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-02 09:07:38 -0300
Processing by Admin::HomeConfigsController#index as HTML
  HomeConfig Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `home_configs`.* FROM `home_configs`   ORDER BY `home_configs`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  AdminUser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users`  WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `admin_users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered /Users/Atua/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@facensAlumni/bundler/gems/activeadmin-dce083189c46/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (598.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 644ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `except' for #<HomeConfig:0x007f887c002d58>:

Started POST "/__better_errors/32ad65699eb25cf6/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-02 09:07:39 -0300
  ContactInfo Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `contact_infos`.* FROM `contact_infos`
```

If I withdraw this code and restart the server, everything works fine. Anyone know what happening?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add more log of error? also please add the code of application controller

Comment: @Vishal I update the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@home_configs = HomeConfig.last
```

This is creating the error. `ActiveAdmin` expects `@home_configs` to be an array. While your code `HomeConfig.last` returns only the last HomeConfig.

You need to change `HomeConfig.last` to something like: `HomeConfig.all`.

Try it and feedback.

Comment: If I change to `HomeConfig.all` for example, I've got another error: `Collection is not a paginated scope. Set collection.page(params[:page]).per(10) before calling :paginated_collection.`

Comment: Could you share the error? that does not help :) Also as mentioned, `@home_configs` should always be an array so this is the way to go. Let's figure out what is the other error and fix it!

Comment: change `@home_configs = HomeConfig.all` to `@home_configs = HomeConfig.all.page(params[:page]).per(10) `.

Comment: Now I have another error :/ with the log `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1652ms. ArgumentError - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`. Did you know what can be this time? Thanks.

Comment: I need more context for the error! Could you post the full logs around the error?

Comment: I think you should start a new question otherwise this is moving toward a chat room :D which is not good for Stackoverflow content quality ;)

Could you mark the answer as correct as it solved your initial problem and answered your question?